# How do I solve a File "<stdin>" error in python?

Tags: python, stdin

I am getting this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print("hello " + friend)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

on a simple code in python. I tried checking the syntax but I don't find anything wrong. Here is the code:

```
friends = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for friend in range(friends):
print("hello "+friend)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and please correctly format your code. Also, even though it has nothing to do with the error you report, you want `friend in friends` not `friend in range(friends)`

Comment: That's not what the error is called. Read the *entire* error message. Then copy and paste it, properly formatted.

Comment: It means the error is occurring in  code that's being executed in the REPL.  The actual exception will be on the next line (`TypeError` in this case).

Comment: ...oh, I see. That is the error that you *will* get after you fix this one. `IndentationError` means exactly what it sounds like: an error caused because your indentation is wrong. The code that you want to happen `for` each item in your list, needs to be indented. Python "expected an indented block" because when a line ends with a `:`, that is a signal that there should be at least one indented line after that.

Comment: Exactly what tutorial or guide are you using to learn Python from?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel coursera

Comment: they used this same example

Comment: Can you give me a URL that lets me see the example for myself, without signing up for a course?

Comment: @JohnColeman still not working

Comment: How exactly are you running the code, given that it's being read from standard input rather than a file like `example.py`?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
friends = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
for friend in friends:
    print("hello "+friend)
```

Gives you the following

> hello a
>   hello b
>   hello c
>   hello d

[image: output]

Comment: still not working

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my end

Comment: @stranger_101 If it isn't working for you then their is something wrong with your workflow involving where and how you are typing and running code.